# How to Select an Option from a Javascript enabled dropdown box on IE using VBA

Tags: javascript, html, vba, excel

Using VBA, I need to select an option out of 6 from a drop down box which is connected to a Javascript which changes the form below based on options selected.

Here is the html codeo on the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    P.when('A','keyword-layout-model').register('keyword-layout-model-instance', 
    function(A, KeywordTargetingModel){
        var model = new KeywordTargetingModel();
        model.updateFromAdType('AAP_CPM');

    A.on("a:dropdown:selected:lineItem.type", function (data) {
        model.updateFromAdType(data.value);
    });

    return model;
})
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    // Create an instance of the ad-type-model. If this is moved, then the documentation
    // in AdTypeModel.js in the D16GRodeoBackbone package needs to be updated.
    P.when('ad-type-model').register('ad-type-model-instance', function(AdTypeModel){
        return new AdTypeModel({adType: 'AAP_CPM'}, {adTypeDropdownId: 'lineItem.type'});
    });
</script>

<span id="lineItem.type_d16g-validation" class="d16g-validation d16g-component d16g-dropdown" for="lineItem.type">{"required":false}</span>
<span class="a-dropdown-container"><select name="lineItem.type" autocomplete="off" id="lineItem.type" tabIndex="-1" class="a-native-dropdown"> 
<option class="a-prompt" value="">Standard display</option>
<option value="AAP_MOBILE_APP">AAP - Mobile app</option>
<option value="AMAN_APP">AMAN - Mobile app</option>
<option value="AAP_MOBILE_WEB">AAP mobile display</option>
<option value="CLASS_I_MOBILE_APP">Class I - Mobile app</option>
<option value="CLASS_I_MOBILE_WEB">Class I - Mobile web</option><option value="CLASS_I_WEB">Class I display</option>
<option value="AAP_CPM" selected>Standard display</option>
<option value="AAP_VIDEO_CPM">Video</option>
</select>

<span tabIndex="-1" id="lineItem.type_controller" data-a-class="a-width-extra-large d16g-dropdownController" class="a-button a-button-dropdown a-width-extra-large d16g-dropdownController"><span class="a-button-inner"><span class="a-button-text a-declarative" data-action="a-dropdown-button" role="button" tabIndex="0" aria-hidden="true"><span class="a-dropdown-prompt">Standard display</span></span><i class="a-icon a-icon-dropdown"></i></span></span></span>&nbsp;

<div id="lineItem.type_error" class="a-box a-alert-inline a-alert-inline-error d16g-hidden d16g-errorMessage" aria-live="assertive" role="alert"><div class="a-box-inner a-alert-container"><i class="a-icon a-icon-alert"></i><div class="a-alert-content"></div></div></div><div id="lineItem.type_serverError" class="a-box a-alert-inline a-alert-inline-error d16g-hidden d16g-serverErrorMessage" aria-live="assertive" role="alert"><div class="a-box-inner a-alert-container"><i class="a-icon a-icon-alert"></i><div class="a-alert-content"></div></div></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
            P.when('D16G', 'jquery-1.9.0', 'A').register('refresh-form-ad-type', function(D16G, $, A) {
                var options = {
    saveButtonId                : "bookAsLineItem",
    classIForecastOverride      : true,
    canBookClassISov            : true,
    retailMerchandising         : false,
    budgetEntryRequired         : true,
    hideDSMLineEntry            : false,
    campaignType                : "BILLABLE",
    canBypassKsoForecast        : false,
    enableKsoOptimization       : false,
    enableKsoBuyingStrategy     : false,
    hasPermissionForViewability : false,
    internalEntity              : true,
    internalUser                : true
};

                A.on("a:dropdown:selected:lineItem.type", function (data) {
                    D16G.Util.setAdType(data.value, options);
                });

                // trigger the initial event at page load
                var id = '#' + D16G.Util.escapeId("lineItem.type");
                A.trigger("a:dropdown:selected:lineItem.type", {value : $(id).val() });

                // Return a function that can be used to trigger a refresh of the page's fields
                return function(){
                    A.trigger("a:dropdown:selected:lineItem.type", {value : $(id).val() })
                };
            });
        </script>             
</div>
```

I have tried using the following VBA code but of no help. Neither the option is getting selected nor the form below is changing. I think there is a javascript which gets triggered but I am unable to figure out how.

```
Set campaignType = IE.document.getElementById("lineItem.type")

For i = 0 To campaignType.Options.Length
  If campaignType.Options(i).Text = "Class I display" Then
      campaignType.selectedIndex = i
       Exit For
   End If
Next i
```

Comment: Is this an internal URL? Or can you share?

Comment: Try firing the onSelect event, or try setting the Option's value directly. E.g. campaignType.FireEvent "MYEVENTNAMEHERE"

Comment: @QHarr - Yes this is an internal url.

Comment: @RyanWildry - What would be the event to be triggered here?

Comment: Could be onSelect, or onChange. What happens when you just set the value of the element?\

Comment: @RyanWildry - The code is not even setting the value of the element. I don't know why.

Comment: @RyanWildry - Any help on why the value is not set would be highly appreciated.