# Select an option from javascript drop-down on a webpage

Tags: javascript, vba, internet-explorer-11

So I have a macro to automate a repetitive task of placing meal orders on a website.
(It's annoying because I have to place one order per person per day, and I'm doing it for a lot of people, and usually do a week at a time)

It's an easy enough process, as it is mostly easy to identify the elements by ID, and just set the values.
However there is a drop-down menu, that then triggers other options on the form, so I need to make the selection and then complete the rest of the form.

```html
<span class="select2-hidden-accessible" role="status" aria-live="polite">Meal Tickets</span>


<div class="select2-drop-mask" id="select2-drop-mask"></div>
<div class="select2-drop select2-display-none select2-drop-active select2-drop-above" id="select2-drop" style="left: 99px; top: 238.67px; width: 1082px; bottom: auto; display: block;">
  <div class="select2-search select2-search-hidden select2-offscreen"> <label class="select2-offscreen" for="s2id_autogen2_search">
               Catering Request Type
                
            </label> <input class="select2-input select2-focused" id="s2id_autogen2_search" role="combobox" aria-expanded="true" aria-activedescendant="select2-result-label-7" aria-owns="select2-results-2" spellcheck="false" aria-autocomplete="list" type="text"
      placeholder="" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" autocomplete="off"> </div>
  <ul class="select2-results" id="select2-results-2" role="listbox">
    <li class="select2-results-dept-0 select2-result select2-result-selectable" role="presentation">
      <div class="select2-result-label" id="select2-result-label-3" role="option"><span class="select2-match"></span>BBQ Request</div>
    </li>
    <li class="select2-results-dept-0 select2-result select2-result-selectable" role="presentation">
      <div class="select2-result-label" id="select2-result-label-4" role="option"><span class="select2-match"></span>Cancel Existing Catering Request</div>
    </li>
    <li class="select2-results-dept-0 select2-result select2-result-selectable" role="presentation">
      <div class="select2-result-label" id="select2-result-label-5" role="option"><span class="select2-match"></span>Consumables and Crib Request</div>
    </li>
    <li class="select2-results-dept-0 select2-result select2-result-selectable" role="presentation">
      <div class="select2-result-label" id="select2-result-label-6" role="option"><span class="select2-match"></span>Function</div>
    </li>
    <li class="select2-results-dept-0 select2-result select2-result-selectable select2-highlighted" role="presentation">
      <div class="select2-result-label" id="select2-result-label-7" role="option"><span class="select2-match"></span>Meal Tickets</div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I found a similar request: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49897167/how-to-select-an-option-from-a-javascript-enabled-dropdown-box-on-ie-using-vba

Comment: I could notice that it is not an HTML Select dropdown. when I run your code, it displays elements in the unordered list. You may need to share the CSS and JS code along with your HTML code. so it could generate the dropdown properly. It could help us test it with the VBA code. After that, we could try to provide possible suggestions for selecting the value in the dropdown. Thanks for your understanding.